# Create "minimally connected" directed acyclic graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic simple graph in NetworkX.

Now, for each edge, that edge has a "source" and a "target".  If there exists a path from the "source" to the "target" *besides* this edge, then I want to delete this edge.

1. Does NetworkX have a built-in function to do this?

I really don't want to re-invent the wheel.

2. [optional] Only in the case that the answer to 1 is "no", then what is the most efficient algorithm to achieve this (for a fairly dense graph)?

Here is an example of a DAG that needs to be cleaned:

- The nodes are:

  ```
  ['termsequence', 'maximumdegree', 'emptymultigraph', 'minimum', 'multiset', 'walk', 'nonemptymultigraph', 'euleriantrail', 'nonnullmultigraph', 'cycle', 'loop', 'abwalk', 'endvertices', 'simplegraph', 'vertex', 'multipletrails', 'edge', 'set', 'stroll', 'union', 'trailcondition', 'nullmultigraph', 'trivialmultigraph', 'sequence', 'multiplepaths', 'path', 'degreevertex', 'onedgesonvertices', 'nontrivialmultigraph', 'adjacentedges', 'adjacentvertices', 'simpleedge', 'maximum', 'multipleloops', 'length', 'circuit', 'class', 'euleriangraph', 'incident', 'minimumdegree', 'orderedpair', 'unique', 'closedwalk', 'multipleedges', 'pathcondition', 'multigraph', 'trail']
  ```
- The edges are:

  ```
  [('termsequence', 'endvertices'), ('emptymultigraph', 'nonemptymultigraph'), ('minimum', 'minimumdegree'), ('multiset', 'trailcondition'), ('multiset', 'pathcondition'), ('multiset', 'multigraph'), ('walk', 'length'), ('walk', 'closedwalk'), ('walk', 'abwalk'), ('walk', 'trail'), ('walk', 'endvertices'), ('euleriantrail', 'euleriangraph'), ('loop', 'simplegraph'), ('loop', 'degreevertex'), ('loop', 'simpleedge'), ('loop', 'multipleloops'), ('endvertices', 'abwalk'), ('vertex', 'adjacentvertices'), ('vertex', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('vertex', 'walk'), ('vertex', 'adjacentedges'), ('vertex', 'multipleedges'), ('vertex', 'edge'), ('vertex', 'multipleloops'), ('vertex', 'degreevertex'), ('vertex', 'incident'), ('edge', 'adjacentvertices'), ('edge', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('edge', 'multipleedges'), ('edge', 'simpleedge'), ('edge', 'adjacentedges'), ('edge', 'loop'), ('edge', 'trailcondition'), ('edge', 'pathcondition'), ('edge', 'walk'), ('edge', 'incident'), ('set', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('set', 'edge'), ('union', 'multiplepaths'), ('union', 'multipletrails'), ('trailcondition', 'trail'), ('nullmultigraph', 'nonnullmultigraph'), ('sequence', 'walk'), ('sequence', 'endvertices'), ('path', 'cycle'), ('path', 'multiplepaths'), ('degreevertex', 'maximumdegree'), ('degreevertex', 'minimumdegree'), ('onedgesonvertices', 'multigraph'), ('maximum', 'maximumdegree'), ('circuit', 'euleriangraph'), ('class', 'multiplepaths'), ('class', 'multipletrails'), ('incident', 'adjacentedges'), ('incident', 'degreevertex'), ('incident', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('orderedpair', 'multigraph'), ('closedwalk', 'circuit'), ('closedwalk', 'cycle'), ('closedwalk', 'stroll'), ('pathcondition', 'path'), ('multigraph', 'euleriangraph'), ('multigraph', 'nullmultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'trivialmultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'nontrivialmultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'emptymultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'euleriantrail'), ('multigraph', 'simplegraph'), ('trail', 'path'), ('trail', 'circuit'), ('trail', 'multipletrails')]
  ```

Comment: Are you sure this is not NP? In other words, is there any algorithm that you know of that solves this problem in polynomial time?

Comment: @Joel I have edited the question.  It is a DAG (no directed cycles).

Comment: @Sait The running time, at worst, would be the number of edges times the running time to find a directed path between a pair of nodes (I don't know what that is specifically.  I would like to find out!)

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I added an example input graph.  Let me know if it's too large.  Thanks!

Comment: Note - there was a silly slowdown in my code.  I kept recalculating G.out_degree(node).  I've modified my code so that a dict is created at the beginning.  This results in an order of magnitude improvement.

Comment: I added some code to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32242282/3577601) that provides optional optimizations.  For example, for a maximally-connected DAG, the complexity is reduced from `O(V**3)` to `O(V**2)`, so for a 4000 node fully connected graph, the runtime is reduced from around 90 seconds (with either Joel's code or my base algorithm) to around 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nx.transitive_reduction(G)`.

Here is an example in the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.transitive_reduction.html).

```py
DG = nx.DiGraph([(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)])
TR = nx.transitive_reduction(DG)
list(TR.edges)  # [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Haha, wow!  Yes, this is great!!

Answer (score 4):

My previous answer deals specifically with the direct question of whether there is a good way to test whether a single edge is redundant.

It looks like you really want a way to remove all redundant edges efficiently.  This means you'd like a way to do them all at once.  It's a different question, but here's an answer to it.  I do not believe networkx has something built in for this, but it is not difficult to find a workable algorithm.

The idea is that since it's a DAG, there are some nodes that have no out-edges.  Start with them and process them.  Once all are processed, then a subset of their parents have no children who haven't been processed.  Go through those parents.  Repeat.  At each stage, the set of unprocessed nodes is a DAG, and we are processing the "end nodes" of that DAG.  It is guaranteed to finish (if the original network is finite).

In the implementation, whenever we process a node, we check first to see whether any child is also an indirect descendant.  If so, delete the edge.  If not, leave it.  When all children are dealt with, we update information for its parents by adding all of its descendants to the set of indirect descendants for the parent.  If all children of the parent are processed, we now add it to our list for next iteration.

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict

def remove_redundant_edges(G):
    processed_child_count = defaultdict(int)  #when all of a nodes children are processed, we'll add it to nodes_to_process
    descendants = defaultdict(set)            #all descendants of a node (including children)
    out_degree = {node:G.out_degree(node) for node in G.nodes_iter()}
    nodes_to_process = [node for node in G.nodes_iter() if out_degree[node]==0] #initially it's all nodes without children
    while nodes_to_process:
        next_nodes = []
        for node in nodes_to_process:
            '''when we enter this loop, the descendants of a node are known, except for direct children.'''
            for child in G.neighbors(node):
                if child in descendants[node]:  #if the child is already an indirect descendant, delete the edge
                    G.remove_edge(node,child)
                else:                                    #otherwise add it to the descendants
                    descendants[node].add(child)
            for predecessor in G.predecessors(node):             #update all parents' indirect descendants
                descendants[predecessor].update(descendants[node])  
                processed_child_count[predecessor]+=1            #we have processed one more child of this parent
                if processed_child_count[predecessor] == out_degree[predecessor]:  #if all children processed, add to list for next iteration.
                    next_nodes.append(predecessor)
        nodes_to_process=next_nodes
```

To test it:

```
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(['termsequence', 'maximumdegree', 'emptymultigraph', 'minimum', 'multiset', 'walk', 'nonemptymultigraph', 'euleriantrail', 'nonnullmultigraph', 'cycle', 'loop', 'abwalk', 'endvertices', 'simplegraph', 'vertex', 'multipletrails', 'edge', 'set', 'stroll', 'union', 'trailcondition', 'nullmultigraph', 'trivialmultigraph', 'sequence', 'multiplepaths', 'path', 'degreevertex', 'onedgesonvertices', 'nontrivialmultigraph', 'adjacentedges', 'adjacentvertices', 'simpleedge', 'maximum', 'multipleloops', 'length', 'circuit', 'class', 'euleriangraph', 'incident', 'minimumdegree', 'orderedpair', 'unique', 'closedwalk', 'multipleedges', 'pathcondition', 'multigraph', 'trail'])
G.add_edges_from([('termsequence', 'endvertices'), ('emptymultigraph', 'nonemptymultigraph'), ('minimum', 'minimumdegree'), ('multiset', 'trailcondition'), ('multiset', 'pathcondition'), ('multiset', 'multigraph'), ('walk', 'length'), ('walk', 'closedwalk'), ('walk', 'abwalk'), ('walk', 'trail'), ('walk', 'endvertices'), ('euleriantrail', 'euleriangraph'), ('loop', 'simplegraph'), ('loop', 'degreevertex'), ('loop', 'simpleedge'), ('loop', 'multipleloops'), ('endvertices', 'abwalk'), ('vertex', 'adjacentvertices'), ('vertex', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('vertex', 'walk'), ('vertex', 'adjacentedges'), ('vertex', 'multipleedges'), ('vertex', 'edge'), ('vertex', 'multipleloops'), ('vertex', 'degreevertex'), ('vertex', 'incident'), ('edge', 'adjacentvertices'), ('edge', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('edge', 'multipleedges'), ('edge', 'simpleedge'), ('edge', 'adjacentedges'), ('edge', 'loop'), ('edge', 'trailcondition'), ('edge', 'pathcondition'), ('edge', 'walk'), ('edge', 'incident'), ('set', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('set', 'edge'), ('union', 'multiplepaths'), ('union', 'multipletrails'), ('trailcondition', 'trail'), ('nullmultigraph', 'nonnullmultigraph'), ('sequence', 'walk'), ('sequence', 'endvertices'), ('path', 'cycle'), ('path', 'multiplepaths'), ('degreevertex', 'maximumdegree'), ('degreevertex', 'minimumdegree'), ('onedgesonvertices', 'multigraph'), ('maximum', 'maximumdegree'), ('circuit', 'euleriangraph'), ('class', 'multiplepaths'), ('class', 'multipletrails'), ('incident', 'adjacentedges'), ('incident', 'degreevertex'), ('incident', 'onedgesonvertices'), ('orderedpair', 'multigraph'), ('closedwalk', 'circuit'), ('closedwalk', 'cycle'), ('closedwalk', 'stroll'), ('pathcondition', 'path'), ('multigraph', 'euleriangraph'), ('multigraph', 'nullmultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'trivialmultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'nontrivialmultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'emptymultigraph'), ('multigraph', 'euleriantrail'), ('multigraph', 'simplegraph'), ('trail', 'path'), ('trail', 'circuit'), ('trail', 'multipletrails')])

print G.size()
>71
print G.order()
>47
descendants = {}  #for testing below
for node in G.nodes():
    descendants[node] = nx.descendants(G,node)

remove_redundant_edges(G)  #this removes the edges

print G.size()  #lots of edges gone
>56
print G.order() #no nodes changed.
>47
newdescendants = {}  #for comparison with above
for node in G.nodes():
    newdescendants[node] = nx.descendants(G,node)

for node in G.nodes():  
    if descendants[node] != newdescendants[node]:
        print 'descendants changed!!'   #all nodes have the same descendants
    for child in G.neighbors(node):  
        if len(list(nx.all_simple_paths(G,node, child)))>1:
            print 'bad edge'  #no alternate path exists from a node to its child.
```

This will be efficient: it has to process every node at the beginning to see whether it is an "end" node.  Then it processes each edge reaching those and checks whether all children of that parent have been processed.  It then looks at those parents and repeats.

Thus it will process each edge once (including glancing at the parent), and each vertex will be dealt with once at the beginning, and then processed once.

Comment: I think this is the best solution.  I wish I had the time to test out all of the solutions on a very large graph, but I will have to get to that later.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple general-purpose algorithm.  The algorithm could be run forwards or backwards.  This and Joel's answer are essentially duals -- his runs backward and this runs forward:

```
def remove_redundant_edges(G):
    """
    Remove redundant edges from a DAG using networkx (nx).
    An edge is redundant if there is an alternate path
    from its start node to its destination node.

    This algorithm could work front to back, or back to front.
    We choose to work front to back.

    The main persistent variable (in addition to the graph
    itself) is indirect_pred_dict, which is a dictionary with
    one entry per graph node.  Each entry is a set of indirect
    predecessors of this node.

    The algorithmic complexity of the code on a worst-case
    fully-connected graph is O(V**3), where V is the number
    of nodes.
    """

    indirect_pred_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for node in nx.topological_sort(G):
        indirect_pred = indirect_pred_dict[node]
        direct_pred = G.predecessors(node)
        for pred in direct_pred:
            if pred in indirect_pred:
                G.remove_edge(pred, node)
        indirect_pred.update(direct_pred)
        for succ in G.successors(node):
            indirect_pred_dict[succ] |= indirect_pred
```

## Complexity analysis and big-O optimizations

For a **minimally connected graph** where each node is only connected to a single edge, the complexity is `O(V+E)`.  However, even for a simple linear graph (where each node has an incoming edge and an outgoing edge), the complexity is `O(V*E)`, and for a **maximally connected graph** (which is the worst case,  where each node is connected to every downstream node on the graph), the complexity is `O(V**3)`.  For this case, the number of ops follows sequence [A000292](https://oeis.org/A000292), which is `n * (n+1) * (n+2) / 6` where n is the number of nodes (V) minus 3.

Depending on the shape of your graph, there are additional optimizations you can do.  Here is a version with a few different optimizers that can dramatically reduce complexity and run-time for some types of graphs:

```
def remove_redundant_edges(G, optimize_dense=True, optimize_chains=True,
                              optimize_tree=False,  optimize_funnel=False):
    """
    Remove redundant edges from a DAG using networkx (nx).
    An edge is redundant if there is an alternate path
    from its start node to its destination node.

    This algorithm could work equally well front to back,
    or back to front. We choose to work front to back.

    The main persistent variable (in addition to the graph
    itself) is indirect_pred_dict, which is a dictionary with
    one entry per graph node.  Each entry is a set of indirect
    predecessors of this node.

    The main processing algorithm uses this dictionary to
    iteratively calculate indirect predecessors and direct
    predecessors for every node, and prune the direct
    predecessors edges if they are also accessible indirectly.
    The algorithmic complexity is O(V**3), where V is the
    number of nodes in the graph.

    There are also several graph shape-specific optimizations
    provided.  These optimizations could actually increase
    run-times, especially for small graphs that are not amenable
    to the optimizations, so if your execution time is slow,
    you should test different optimization combinations.

    But for the right graph shape, these optimizations can
    provide dramatic improvements.  For the fully connected
    graph (which is worst-case), optimize_dense reduces the
    algorithmic complexity from O(V**3) to O(V**2).

    For a completely linear graph, any of the optimize_tree,
    optimize_chains, or optimize_funnel options would decrease
    complexity from O(V**2) to O(V).

    If the optimize_dense option is set to True, then an
    optimization phase is before the main algorithm.  This
    optimization phase works by looking for matches between
    each node's successors and that same node's successor's
    successors (by only looking one level ahead at a time).

    If the optimize_tree option is set true, then a phase is
    run that will optimize trees by working right-to-left and
    recursively removing leaf nodes with a single predecessor.
    This will also optimize linear graphs, which are degenerate
    trees.

    If the optimize_funnel option is set true, then funnels
    (inverted trees) will be optimized.

    If the optimize_chains option is set true, then chains
    (linear sections) will be optimized by sharing the
    indirect_pred_dict sets.  This works because Python
    checks to see if two sets are the same instance before
    combining them.

    For a completely linear graph, optimize_funnel or optimize_tree
    execute more quickly than optimize_chains.  Nonetheless,
    optimize_chains option is enabled by default, because
    it is a balanced algorithm that works in more cases than
    the other two.
    """

    ordered = nx.topological_sort(G)

    if optimize_dense:
        succs= dict((node, set(G.successors(node))) for node in ordered)
        for node in ordered:
            my_succs = succs.pop(node)
            kill = set()
            while my_succs:
                succ = my_succs.pop()
                if succ not in kill:
                    check = succs[succ]
                    kill.update(x for x in my_succs if x in check)
            for succ in kill:
                G.remove_edge(node, succ)

    indirect_pred_dict = dict((node, set()) for node in ordered)

    if optimize_tree:
        remaining_nodes = set(ordered)
        for node in reversed(ordered):
            if G.in_degree(node) == 1:
                if not (set(G.successors(node)) & remaining_nodes):
                    remaining_nodes.remove(node)
        ordered = [node for node in ordered if node in remaining_nodes]

    if optimize_funnel:
        remaining_nodes = set(ordered)
        for node in ordered:
            if G.out_degree(node) == 1:
                if not (set(G.predecessors(node)) & remaining_nodes):
                    remaining_nodes.remove(node)
        ordered = [node for node in ordered if node in remaining_nodes]

    if optimize_chains:
        # This relies on Python optimizing the set |= operation
        # by seeing if the objects are identical.
        for node in ordered:
            succs = G.successors(node)
            if len(succs) == 1 and len(G.predecessors(succs[0])) == 1:
                indirect_pred_dict[succs[0]] = indirect_pred_dict[node]

    for node in ordered:
        indirect_pred = indirect_pred_dict.pop(node)
        direct_pred = G.predecessors(node)
        for pred in direct_pred:
            if pred in indirect_pred:
                G.remove_edge(pred, node)
        indirect_pred.update(direct_pred)
        for succ in G.successors(node):
            indirect_pred_dict[succ] |= indirect_pred
```

I have not analyzed whether it is possible to construct a dense, yet non-maximally-connected graph that executes with complexity greater than `O(V**2)` with the optimize_dense option enabled, but I have no reason, *a priori*, to believe that it is not possible.  The optimization works best for a a maximally-connected graph, and would not do anything, for example, in the case where each node shares successors with its grandchilden instead of its children, and I have not analyzed the run-time of this case.

## Example Testbench

I have stripped down the code for the base algorithm and added instrumentation that records the number of ops required by the worst-case path, and an example test generator that generates maximally-connected graphs.

```
import collections
import networkx as nx

def makegraph(numnodes):
    """
    Make a fully-connected graph given a number of nodes
    """
    edges = []
    for i in range(numnodes):
        for j in range(i+1, numnodes):
            edges.append((i, j))
    return nx.DiGraph(edges)

def remove_redundant_edges(G):
    ops = 0
    indirect_pred_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for node in nx.topological_sort(G):
        indirect_pred = indirect_pred_dict[node]
        direct_pred = G.predecessors(node)
        for pred in direct_pred:
            if pred in indirect_pred:
                G.remove_edge(pred, node)
        indirect_pred.update(direct_pred)
        for succ in G.successors(node):
            indirect_pred_dict[succ] |= indirect_pred
            ops += len(indirect_pred)
    return ops

def test_1(f, numnodes):
    G = makegraph(numnodes)
    e1 = nx.number_of_edges(G)
    ops = f(G)
    e2 = nx.number_of_edges(G)
    return ops, e1, e2

for numnodes in range(30):
    a = test_1(remove_redundant_edges, numnodes)
    print numnodes, a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You want to use `all_simple_paths`[[documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html)] (which provides a generator of, well, all simple paths between the two). Quit as soon as it finds the second, so that it doesn't calculate all of them.

Once this is defined you want to look at each edge and if there is more than one path from the source to the target, you delete the edge.

```
def multiple_paths(G,source,target):
    '''returns True if there are multiple_paths, False otherwise'''
    path_generator = nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=target)
    counter = 0
    for path in path_generator: #test to see if there are multiple paths
        counter += 1
        if counter >1:  
            break  #instead of breaking, could have return True
    if counter >1:  #counter == 2
        return True
    else:  #counter == 0 or 1
        return False

import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1), (1,2), (1,3), (0,3), (2,3)])
multiple_paths(G,0,1)
> False
multiple_paths(G,0,2) 
> False
multiple_paths(G,0,3)
> True

for edge in G.edges_iter():  #let's do what you're trying to do
    if multiple_paths(G, edge[0], edge[1]):
        G.remove_edge(edge[0],edge[1])

G.edges()
> [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

---

Note, you could also delete the edge and then run `has_path` to see if there's still a path.  If not, then add the edge back.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1), (1,2), (1,3), (0,3), (2,3)])
for edge in G.edges_iter():
    G.remove_edge(edge[0],edge[1])
    if not nx.has_path(G,edge[0],edge[1]):
        G.add_edge(edge[0],edge[1])

G.edges()
> [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

you'll want to be careful if there is any edge data though, and I don't like the possibility of deleting the edge and then adding it back --- it opens up the chance for some difficult to find bugs.

Comment: Any idea about the runtime of these two strategies and how they compare?  In particular, do you think `has_path` and `path_generator` are (virtually) the same timewise?  I'm assuming that the path_generator only looks for paths one at a time, as the for loop requests them.

Comment: Checking the documentation, `has_path` is based on `shortest_path` which is itself based on `bidirectional_shortest_path`.  I believe this will work faster than `all_simple_paths`, which apparently uses a depth first search.  The benefit of the bidirectional path can be imagined by thinking of two points in 3D space.  Expanding a balloon around of them until it reaches the other (corresponding to exploring all paths out from one) requires a lot of air.  It's much less air to expand balloons about both of them until they touch.  This may be slower if there is no path...  I don't know for sure.

Comment: Looks like the followup comment I wrote didn't appear.  I would recommend running a few examples with both approaches for a few sample networks.  I would expect `has_path` to be faster if there is a path, but `all_simple_paths` to be faster if there is not (I haven't tested however).  So which is faster may depend on network structure and size in nontrivial ways.

Comment: It's not a full answer, and you now have a full answer which is completely different -- why would you want people bothering with this -- this isn't what they came here for...

Comment: @PatrickMaupin As you note - it is a completely different answer.  There is value in that.  You're incorrect in saying it's not a full answer.  It provides exactly the command that the OP was asking for.  The fact that I have a *completely different* answer that provides what the OP actually wanted doesn't mean that someone trying to address a very similar question in the future wouldn't want to see this.  Tell me honestly, if you wanted to do this to a single edge (possibly not even in a DAG), would you want the other solution I gave, or this one?

Comment: Let me unpack what I meant by not a full answer -- you didn't package it all up into a single "remove all the nodes" function.  And if you _had_ done so, it would be incredibly slow.  And no, I don't personally think it's useful _under this question_, and I don't even think it's Pythonic -- for example you use an ugly for-loop instead of itertools.slice.